# How to find the sum of a row given position requirements in excel

Tags: excel

[image: Here is a link to some of the data i am trying to work with]

I want to be able to take the data presented and fill in another table where the columns are weekday (mon, tues, wed, thurs), weekends (fr, sat , sund) and the rows are the week numbers. The data i need are the sums. For example, how can i extract the sum of all the weekdays/weekends for week 1

Comment: SUMIFS perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with either SUMPRODUCT or SUMIFS.  Each has its advantages.  SUMPRODUCT supports a multi-column range, so the formula is simpler, but it's also not as standard, so it's a little harder to read.  I have included the data and formulas in a Google Sheet, but I did this on Excel first and just transferred them here for ease of demonstration.  Let me know if this helps.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BAnfIb6MtltkPERnuDN3w6BnP55mlsJOwv1xc5GaWHE/edit#gid=0

Here I have some sample random data in a table, along with some weeknumbers and daynumbers.  Your numbers did not look like they were standard, so I didn't try to duplicate them.  I just used Excel's standard functions.  This will only make a difference in the condition for determining weekends vs weekdays, where I have used 1 and 7.  You will just need to replace here with whatever your numbers are.

The SUMPRODUCT versions is relatively straightforward.  We use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$31=$R3) * (($D$3:$D$31=1)+($D$3:$D$31=7)) * ($E$3:$I$31))
```

to get the weekends sums, where the first condition is the week number, the second is the day number, and the last is the data range.  We invert the day number condition to get the weekday sums:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$31=$R3) * (NOT(($D$3:$D$31=1)+($D$3:$D$31=7))) * ($E$3:$I$31))
```

The advantage of the SUMPRODUCT is that it supports a multi-column data range, the condition is easily invertible, and if you are familiar with the construction it is relatively simple to follow.  A disadvantage is that it may confuse some, and it also doesn't support full columns, meaning you will have to resize the column references if the data changes.

---

SUMIFS will support full column references, meaning you will only have to write it once, and more people are familiar with SUMIFS, but it also doesn't support multi-column sum ranges, so you have to write five separate sumifs, one for each of the columns in the data set and then add them.  Here the IF conditions are simple.  One to match the week number and two to make sure the day number doesn't match a weekend.

The weekend variation on the SUMIFS formula is not going to work in Google Sheets, because Sheets handles the arrays slightly differently.  It should work in Excel.  What we are doing in that is passing SUMIFS an array constant containing the weekend  numbers `{1,7}`, and Excel will generate two columns of results, one for each element of the array constant.  To prevent a spill we pass that array to SUM, to get a final total.  This gives us the ability to use an OR style logic in SUMIFS.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a little harder to understand ( i'm quite new to excel), but the sumproduct approach worked wonderfully. Out of curiosity, when i used the sumproduct and put commas between the arguments, which is what ive always done, the formula did not work. When i changed them to '*' it worked fine, why is that?

Comment: Ah, because sumproduct expects you to pass it arrays of matching dimensions, then it multiplies the matching elements in each array and returns the sum.  But in this case, the first two arguments produce a single column array containing TRUE or FALSE, and the last argument is the multicolumn data range.  So if you pass the three elements as SUMPRODUCT expects, it will find the arrays are mismatched and return an error.

Comment: But SUMPRODUCT will also work if it is only passed one array, in which case it will return the sum of the array.  So we take advantage of this to return a sum based on conditions.  When you multiply an array by something, Excel will return an array of the same size.  In this case, we are multiplying the array holding the data by a single column array containing TRUE or FALSE, essentially 1 or 0, and so Excel takes the array containing the data, multiplies each element by 1 or 0 and returns that.  If you pass the resulting array to SUMPRODUCT, then it sees one array and returns the sum of it.

Comment: Anyway, glad this helped, if it solved your problem, please accept it as the answer.  And maybe upvote it too :)